# Why is "な" in "円滑な活動を助ける" not "に"?

Tags: particle-に, particle-な

why is "円滑" an Adjective not an Adverb in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because 円滑 adjectivally modifies 活動, not 助ける, in this sentence. What's smooth in this context is the 活動 (activity) itself, not the manner of helping/promoting. In other words, the speaker wants to say "smooth activity", not "to help/promote smoothly."

Answer (score 0):

it can be either adj or adv but the meaning will change, if it's a noun phrase like here na-adj is required

Comment: What's different between them?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer to include examples showing how your answer works?